# Flutter - Is there anything similar to sync adapter in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, synchronization, android-syncadapter

I wanted to sync my local DB with my server. In Android we have sync Adapter that does the work and make life easier. I would wonder if we have something similar in Flutter or how can I do that in flutter.

Answer (score 1):

[Sync-adapters](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter) are core Android components. Flutter cannot directly provide a replacement for them. However, flutter does provide a mechanism to use platform specific APIs called [`flutter plugin`](https://medium.com/flutter-community/creating-a-flutter-plugin-dialog-box-78adbff15fe). And although their are a lot of plugins already present, their is still a bit lack of plugins providing such core platform support.

Ideally, in an android application, the sync adapters are background services which can be triggered by the OS itself in a separate process, so the simplest way would be to do the following :

1. Create a separate sync-adapter inside the `android` directory of your flutter app. Make sure you correctly follow all the requirements for the sync-adapter to work. The documentation is in [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter).
2. Create a simple plugin-mechanism using [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/creating-a-flutter-plugin-dialog-box-78adbff15fe) to invoke android APIs corresponding to the sync-adapter.

Also note that all this code - Android sync-adapter, flutter-plugin and your flutter-app, can simply reside in current code base. You are NOT REQUIRED to create a separate "plugin" to actually use the plugin.

Comment: Thank for your response. Yes, we can create a plugin that works for Android. But I was looking for something that I can use for Android and IOS as well. In this case I have to create another platform channel for IOS. But I am not into IOS.
Can't we use any plugin that work in background and can do something similar to sync adapter.

Comment: maybe something like [this](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) and [that](https://medium.com/vrt-digital-studio/flutter-workmanager-81e0cfbd6f6e)

Comment: Sure. This can be used. Let me try and thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hi @vikaspandey did you find any solution? I am looking for something similar, want to sync my contacts to server in flutter.